# How to set up a concrete Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> to a mock in a unit test through Moq?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

I have the following method in my repository:

```
  Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

I call it in the service in the following way:

```
 var itemToUpdate = await _unitOfWork.ItemsRepository
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == itemDto.Id && x.UserId == userId);
```

The question is how to call it in the unit test? I have a strict mock for ItemsRepository and when I call it like this, I get an Exception that it is a strict mock and there is no set up for my scenario:

```
            ItemsRepositoryMock
            .Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1 && x.UserId == "ab70793b-cec8-4eba-99f3-cbad0b1649d0", null, CancellationToken.None))
            .ReturnsAsync(firstItem);
```

How should I set up the mock with exactly the parameters I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot setup it directly in Moq. The reason is that those expressions are not equal as far as c# is concerned.

What you could do...

1. is write your own comparison of expressions and depending on what is allowed in that expression it can be easier or harder to do. You setup mock with

   ```
   It.Is<Expression<Func<TheEntity, bool>>(actual=>CompareExpressions(actual, x=>x => x.Id == 1 && x.UserId == "ab70793b-cec8-4eba-99f3-cbad0b1649d0")
   ```

and implement

```
CompareExpressions<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> actual,Func<TEntity, bool> expected)
```

traversing expression trees and doing Assert.Fail when you detect a difference its not that difficult but if you haven't done it before it can be a challenge especially if you would like to allow equivalent and not identical expressions. Good point to start would be:
[ExpressionComparison](https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/master/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Expressions/ExpressionComparison.cs)

2. or you could compile expression and call it with a matching element you can just do

   ```
   It.Is<Expression<Func<TheEntity, bool>>(actual=>CompareExpressions(actual, new[]{ 
            new Sample<TheEntity>{ Subject= new TheEntity{ /*...*/ }, Expected = true, 
            new Sample /*...*/ )

   CompareExpressions(Func<TEntity, bool> actual, List<TEntity> samples) 
   {
       var method = actual.Compile(); 
       foreach(var sample in sampes)
          Assert.AreEqual(sample.Expected, method(sample.Subject));
   }
   ```

Second method is easier but has potential of false positive if you prepare not good enough samples.